# Calculate $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(e^{\sin x}+ \sin x)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}-(e^{\tan x}+ \tan x)^{\frac{1}{\tan x}}}{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate the following limit?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{(e^{\sin x}+ \sin x)^{\frac{1}{\sin x}}-(e^{\tan x}+ \tan x)^{\frac{1}{\tan x}}}{x^3}$$

I thought of L'Hopital's rule, Taylor expansion, and limit the form of $e^x$, but the presence of $\sin x$ and $\tan x$ make it hard to apply them. Could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Try graphing and see what happens?[Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kqnrzhnea2). You can also take exp(ln($\lim_1$))-exp(ln($\lim_2$)). To combine and get rid of the terms. The notation here means split the fraction and take the natural logarithm of each separately. Then to make the same, take exp(y) of each term separately not cancelling, but rather using logarithm properties.

Comment: You may note that both terms in numerator tend to $e^2$ and hence we can replace them by their logarithm and multiply the resulting expression by $e^2$. That should lead to a lot of simplification.

Comment: Please try to proceed with the hint in last comment and let us know if that helps. Also it would be great if you can update the question with your work.

Comment: Seems to be a good question! Could you kindly mention the book, if it's not too much of a hassle?

Answer (score 5):

Hint 1: Consider the Taylor series of $f(\sin(x)) - f(\tan(x))$ for a general function $f$. What information do you need about $(e^x + x)^{1/x}$ to solve the problem?

Hint 2:

> The information can be gotten from the Taylor series for $\ln(e^x + x)/x$, which is easier to find.

Full solution:

> You can verify by substitution of Taylor series that if we have a function $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$, then $f(\sin x) - f(\tan x) = -f'(0) x^3/2 + O(x^4)$. So we simply need to find the derivative of $f(x) = (e^x + x)^{1/x}$ at $0$. Since we only need the first derivative, it'll be easier to look at $\ln(f(x)) = \ln(e^x + x)/x$ instead. The numerator can be easily expanded in power series, and we get $$\frac{\ln(e^x + x)}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(2x - \frac{3}{2} x^2 + \frac{11}{6} x^3 + O(x^4)\right) = 2 - \frac{3}{2}x + \frac{11}{6}x^2 + O(x^3)$$ So we have $\ln(f(0)) = 2$ and $\ln(f(x))'|_0 = -3/2$. Using $\ln(f(x))' = f'(x)/f(x)$, we have $f'(0) = -3e^2/2$. Thus, \begin{multline}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(e^{\sin x} - \sin x)^{1/\sin x} - (e^{\tan x} - \tan x)^{1/\tan x}}{x^3} \\= \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{x^3}\left[\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3e^2}{2}\right)x^3 + O(x^4)\right) = \frac{3e^2}{4} \end{multline}

Comment: @DatBoi whoops, forgot the $-1/2$ from earlier in the solution.

Comment: Very nice solution nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$(e^{\sin x}+\sin x)^{\frac {1}{\sin x}}=e^{\frac {\ln(e^{\sin x}+\sin x)}{\sin x}}=e^{1+\frac {\ln(1+\frac {\sin x}{e^{\sin x}})}{\sin x}}=e(e^{e^{-\sin x}})=e^{2-\sin x+\frac {\sin^2 x}{2}}$$
Now, one more application of Taylor Series would create a polynomial in $\sin x$. To do this make sure to keep $e^2$ separate first. You can do the same thing with $\tan x$.
So, you get a polynomial in $\sin x$ and $\tan x$, after which you can evaluate the limit using L'Hôspital rule, because the indeterminate part of it will factorise to create a simple limit.

Comment: $\ln(e^{\sin x} + \sin x)/\sin x  = 1 +  \ln(1 + \sin x / e^{\sin x})/\sin x$, not $\ln(1 + \sin x / e^{\sin x})$.

Comment: Ok I edited. Thanks